# Maximum Eigenvalue Lemma

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to learn about consistency of matrix in AHP (Analytic Hierarchy Process). One of the way is by the maximum eigenvalue. But I am having a problem to understand and prove this lemma. Can anyone help me how to prove this lemma?

---

Let $R_n^+ = \{x=(x_1,x_2,....,x_n)^T|x_i>0,i=1,2,...,n\}$

**Lemma 2.1** (Perron). Let $A = (a_{ij})$ be an $nxn$ positive matrix and $\lambda_{max}$ be the maximal eigenvalue of $A$. Then

$$\lambda_{max}=\min_{x\in R_n^+} \max_i \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} \frac{x_j}{x_i}$$

Let $A$ and $\lambda_{max}$ be as in Lemma 2.1. The positive right eigenvextor corresponding to $\lambda_{max}$ is called the principal right eigenvector $A$.

---

Thank you.

Lemma source: Z. S. Xu, C. P. Wei, A Consistency Improving Method in the Analytic Hierarchy Process, *European Journal of Operational Research*, 1999, 116: 443-449

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: In a first approach, it looks connected to the Courant-Fisher-Weyl theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem)